# php behaving unexpectedly. Isset function is changing the property of a class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using PHP 8.0 and Codeigniter 4.1.7

while in a class i have a protected type property name "db" having a builder type object in it.

```
public function setOption($optionName, $optionValue) {
    d($this->db);
    isset($this->{$optionName});
    dd($this->db);
}
```

after running three statements in the function, the "db" property changed, however there is no assignment statement there.

d() and dd() are the debugging function provided by Klint in codeigniter 4. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/testing/debugging.html?highlight=debug

Below is the screenshot.

[image: Picture showing Builder type object is changed to Connection]

Comment: Why are you using two different debug functions when trying to test for the same result?

Comment: *after running three statements in the function*: what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @Clive d is the function without die or exit, while dd is the function that die or exit. i want to stop execution after 2nd debug. If you read this https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/testing/debugging.html?highlight=debug you will be clear.

Comment: @Vickel, my mistake i want to say that when i use debug function d before isset($this->{$optionName}); statement it has builder object in it. but when i use debug function dd after this statement it has Connection object in it. I also tried with d instead of dd. Same thing happened. Tecnically $this->db should not change.